# Decoding hexacode with multiple encodings

Tags: python, hex, decode, encode

We have multiple hexadecimals strings which represent a user message. These strings went trough several legacy systems, here is my code to decode those values:

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs

df = pd.read_csv("testBDD.csv")

for index in df.index:

   hexCode = str(df['hex'][index])
   hexCode = hexCode[2:]
   bytes_array = bytes.fromhex(hexCode)
   Msg = bytes_array.decode(encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
   print(Msg)
```

and I get:

> "message": "La maison n'\u00e9tant plus habit\u00e9e depuis le mois d'octobre 2019 (vide de meubles) je souhaite r\u00e9silier l'abonnement ainsi qu'\u00eatre d\u00e9grev\u00e9 de la taxe de collecte et de traitement des eaux us\u00e9es \u00e0 compter du 1er janvier 2020 si possible. J'ai une attestation de la mairie de

We note that we still have some encoded parts, my question would be: how to handle those parts? Is there a way we can decode further this message?

The message is originally in French, my opinion is that special characters such as "é", "à" etc... have been encoded multiple times by the legacy system hence their presence.

Comment: An example for a string: `x=r"qu'\u00eatre d\u00e9grev\u00e9"; print(x)` returns `qu'\u00eatre d\u00e9grev\u00e9` however `print( x.encode( 'raw_unicode_escape').decode( 'unicode_escape'))` returns `qu'être dégrevé` . Hard to give better advice without a [mcve] (sanitized part of `"testBDD.csv"`)…

Comment: There was a lot of private data that couldn't be shared, but your answer worked perfectly, thanks a lot !!